# Import certificates into windows from certificate and private key

Tags: windows, ssl

I am having an issue importing a certificate into windows, its a one off requirement and something that I have little experience with, I have been provided a certificate file and a private key file.

I cannot fathom how to import these into windows so that they will be available in ISS to be assigned to a web site.

I have attempted to use open SSL to create a PFX as I know how to import those.. but when I try I get the message

```
unable to load private key
14828:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Hopefully this will give some indication of the file formats, the header in the PK is -

----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

And the header in the crt file is

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Somewhere between being issued and sent to me, someone has opened the file and re-saved it changing the encoding.

Opened the file in notepad++ changed the encoding to ANSI, saved and re-ran the openssl command and its exported the PFX.